# Open Custom Views panel from VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I would like to open Custom Views panel from VBA.
I'm aware I can open CustomViews.Add and .Show calls but all I need is to call on the existing panel. Is there a way to control the GUI pf Excel from VBA? I din't find it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can execute ribbon commands using the `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` method:

```
application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "ViewCustomViews"
```

The easiest way to find the right name to execute, IMO, is to use the Customize Ribbon dialog to locate the control you want, then hover over the control in the list and look at the tooltip.

NB: The button name you use is **case-sensitive** so pay close attention to how it appears in the tooltip!